# Cannot resolve scoped service 'FluentValidation.IValidatorFactory' from root provider

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-5, swashbuckle, fluentvalidation

I have an issue running an app that I took over from a different contractor. I've added existing projects references (before those projects were NuGet packages hosted on a private feed). Those packages are written in .net5.0, app main code in netcore3.1, I had to upgrade packages and projected. Right now I'm getting following issue when my app gets any HTTP request:

```
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteValidator.ValidateResolution(Type serviceType, IServiceScope scope, IServiceScope rootScope)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IServiceProviderEngineCallback.OnResolve(Type
 serviceType, IServiceScope scope)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineSco
pe)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
         at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.ConfigureSwaggerGeneratorOptions.CreateFilter[TFilter](FilterDescriptor filterDescriptor)
         at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.ConfigureSwaggerGeneratorOptions.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Configure>b__2(FilterDescriptor filterDescriptor)
         at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)
         at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.ConfigureSwaggerGeneratorOptions.Configure(SwaggerGeneratorOptions options)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<Get>b__0()
         at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
         at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
         at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
         at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
         at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd(String name, Func`1 createOptions)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.Get(String name)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.get_Value()
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.SwaggerGenServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c.<AddSwaggerGen>b__0_1(IServiceProvider s)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext co
ntext)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverConte
xt context)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext co
ntext)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scop
e)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineSco
pe)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type middleware)
         at lambda_method2(Closure , Object , HttpContext , IServiceProvider )
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass5_1.<UseMiddleware>b__2(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.HostFilteringMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingApplication.ProcessRequestAsync(Context context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
```

I've checked FluentValidation configuration and it's analogic to FV documentation. I'm running out of ideas :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had quite the same problem in combination with Swashbuckle and it worked when I didn't use the newest releases:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="FluentValidation.AspNetCore" Version="9.5.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations" Version="5.6.3" />
```

Comment: I came to the same solution. Marking your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

If you are calling `AddFluentValidationRules` inside `AddSwaggerGen`, try removing that (it's marked obsolete), and instead call `services.AddFluentValidationRulesToSwagger()` on your service collection. That fixed it for me.

Comment: I think this is the correct aproach!